# Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-paytm'

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, paytm

Using the following code at config.xml but Plugin error (you probably need to remove plugin files from your app) is coming.

It also shows that "paytmcordova.xml" not found!, Also please suggest how to use this file at phonegap - cordova.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-paytm" source="npm" spec="~0.0.6">
      <variable name="MERCHANT_ID" value="XXXXXXXXXX" />
   <variable name="INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID" value="Retail" />
   <variable name="WEBSITE" value="WEBSTAGING" />
</plugin>
```

Please guide how to solve the issue.